# Зачем изучать грамматику в школе?

Tags: обучение, образование

Спрашивал у учителей биологии, физики, английского - никто не знает, что такое "придаточные определительные". Они все очень хорошие учителя. Они учились в школе, и не помнят, не используют знания грамматики на практике.

А вы знаете кого-нибудь взрослого (не специалиста), кто знает русскую грамматику? Если нет, то зачем учеников мучают в школе? Смотрел задания ЕГЭ - даже там очень мало грамматики, больше заданий на понимание и на орфографию.

**Niemand**, синусы и косинусы есть в ЕГЭ и даже во ФГОСе (решение тригонометрических уравнений входит в число умений выпускника). "Придаточных определительных" во ФГОСе нет, и нет даже в ЕГЭ, т.е. государственный стандарт не требует этих знаний (и не осуществляется их проверка на выходе).

Всем "голосующим": вопрос мотивации является центральным вопросом любой методики преподавания. Как объяснить ученику необходимость изучения некоторых областей знаний, если а) взрослые культурные люди не обладают этими знаниями и б) даже государство не требует их вводить в программу обучения?

**Людмила**, вот ссылка на ФГОС, который я изучал: [http://минобрнауки.рф/документы/543](http://%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8.%D1%80%D1%84/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B/543) - на этой странице можно скачать сам документ ([ПРИКАЗ от 6 октября 2009 г. № 413](http://%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8.%D1%80%D1%84/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B/543/%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB/4588/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%20%D0%9E%D0%B1%20%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20413.rtf) «Об утверждении и введении в действие федерального государственного образовательного стандарта среднего общего образования»). В документе нет ничего про синтаксис сложного предложения. Есть много разных требований (например, "*владение умением анализировать текст с точки зрения наличия в нем явной и скрытой, основной и второстепенной информации*"), но конкретно про синтаксис - ничего.

Уточняю: я изучал задания **ЕГЭ** (не ОГЭ) и ФГОС **среднего общего образования**. В ЕГЭ нет заданий на синтаксис сложного предложения (хотя есть на пунктуацию).

Задания ОГЭ (ГИА) я изучал в прошлом году - там тоже не было терминов вида "определительные" или "изъяснительные", было о предложениях с "по­сле­до­ва­тель­ным и од­но­род­ным под­чи­не­ни­ем при­да­точ­ных". Посмотрел сейчас на указанной выше странице Минобрнауки ФГОС **основного общего образования** - там тоже нет конкретики о синтаксисе.

**Sibylla**, можете привести пример **неграмотного** использования придаточных определительных? "*Мы научились говорить и писать по правилам*" - **Вы, Sibylla,** научились; 90% других учеников - нет.

**behemothus**, хорошо: вот вы, не специалист (как я понимаю, без специального образования), скажем, неплохо разбираетесь в русской грамматике. Такое бывает, когда человеку просто интересен предмет; вам, видимо, нравится изучать грамматику. Я думаю, на этом форуме как раз и собрались в основном такие люди. Но знаете ли вы кого-то знающего грамматику (отличающего "изъяснительные" от "определительных") - человека не с этого (и не с другого лингвистического) форума?

**Людмила**:

> А сама грамматика, и синтаксис в том числе, необходима школьнику, чтобы привести в порядок знания и умения в области пунктуации, чтобы он видел всё предложение и умел объяснить и поставить знаки препинания.

Нет, **Людмила**, знание грамматики нужно вовсе не для постановки запятых! Такое ваше понимание вопроса как раз и разрушает, выхолащивает школьное образование. Даже наше правительство уже это поняло. И поэтому ФГОС (среднего общего образования) давно уже требует от выпускников отнюдь не "пунктуационную", а "коммуникативную компетенцию". И "когнитивную": распознавание текста, понимание мыслей автора и умение выразить и аргументировать свои мысли. И именно поэтому я задал здесь этот вопрос - потому что огромное (колоссальное?) количество учителей (и хороших, и опытных) не видят этих перемен.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос ни о чем.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что хорошие учителя биологии, физики, английского  **грамотно используют в своей речи "придаточные определительные", даже не зная их названия**, то есть все-таки применяют  знания грамматики на практике.

Для чего мы вообще в школе 10-11 лет изучаем правила письма и грамматику, тратя на это "колоссальное" время, неужели для того, чтобы потом всё забыть?

Думаю, что нет. Мы научились говорить и писать по правилам, правила помогали нам избежать ошибок в нашей устной и письменной речи, они останавливали наше внимание на трудных грамматических формах, на вариантах письма, среди которых нужно выбрать правильный.

А потом -  **"мавр сделал свое дело, мавр может уходить"**, и основная часть прекрасных учителей и просто неплохих российских граждан обладают грамотной речью **на интуитивном уровне** - не помня школьных правил, "не зная" школьной грамматики.

Наверное, это средний уровень знания языка, и от врожденной интуиции он во многом   зависит, и с практической деятельностью человека связан (прежде всего, с чтением книг на различные темы), но думаю, что без обучения в школе наша речь была бы проще, неправильнее, примитивнее, и в целом мы бы намного хуже владели русским языком.

Comment: "Врождённая интуиция" – что за зверь такой?!

Comment: Об этом  можно, к примеру, прочитать в книге «Врожденная интуиция» Л. Тибодо, так что "зверь", то есть термин,  реально существует. Но я-то  имела в виду врожденное чувство языка у хороших писателей, которые интуитивно чувствуют правильный грамматический строй текста.

Comment: Это же мистика.

Comment: Интуиция - это мистика? Но в словаре эти понятия определяются по-разному. МИСТИКА, 1. Вера в существование сверхъестественных, фантастических сил, с которыми таинственным образом связан и может общаться человек.  2. Разг. Нечто загадочное, непонятное, совершенно необъяснимое. ИНТУИЦИЯ,1. Безотчётное неосознанное чувство, подсказывающее правильное поведение, понимание чего-л.; чутьё. Сила интуиции. Полагаться на интуицию.

Comment: Нет, мистика – это "врождённая интуиция". Это как раз именно нечто сверхъестественное, фантастическое. Врождённой интуиции не бывает.

Comment: Я согласна с этим ответом, кроме слова «врожденная». Эта интуиция действительно существует, но она появляется с опытом использования языка. Иногда достаточно много читать, но еще лучше и читать, и изучать грамматику.  Для сравнения можно представить человека, который легко и быстро решает дифференциальные уравнения. Очевидно, что интуиция, которая подсказывает способ решения, возникла от предыдущего опыта решения дифференциальных уравнений. Хотя конечно, разным людям может понадобиться разный объем опыта для достижения интуиции.

Answer (score 3):

```
               "Придаточных определительных" во ФГОСе нет, и нет даже
          в   ЕГЭ, т.е. государственный стандарт не требует этих знаний
                        (и не осуществляется их проверка на выходе).
```

Где это Вы такой ФГОС нашли? Там написано:
Синтаксис
...Сложное предложение 5.9 Сложные бессоюзные предложения. Смысловые отношения между частями сложного бессоюзного предложения 5.10 Сложные предложения с разными видами связи между частями 5.11 Способы передачи чужой речи 5.12 Синтаксический анализ простого предложения 5.13 Синтаксический анализ сложного предложения 5.14 Синтаксический анализ (обобщение)

Определительное придаточное входит как раз в "Синтаксический анализ сложного предложения". А Вы хотели бы, чтоб там перечисляли всю классификацию предложений?

И все учебные программы основаны на этом стандарте. Так что Вы не правы,  **государство  требует их вводить в программу обучения**, и на выходе эти знания проверяются в ОГЭ в 9 классе, там есть задание найти в тексте предложения разного типа, в том числе и СПП с разного типа придаточными или с обособленными членами - определениями, приложениями и т.д. В ЕГЭ действительно больше практической грамотности. А сама грамматика, и синтаксис в том числе,необходима школьнику, чтобы привести в порядок знания и умения в области пунктуации,чтобы он видел всё предложение и умел объяснить и поставить знаки препинания.

Насчёт Ваших знакомых учителей, это они просто от Вас отмахнулись,не хотелось вспоминать, напрягаться,тем более учитель английского, иначе он не лингвист, а самозванец.Я уверена, что школьные знания такого формата в головах остаются, достаточно чуть напомнить.

Мои некоторые ученики тоже возмущались в школе, что я их заставляла Пушкина учить, спрашивали, где он им пригодится ( в тракторе будет читать или коровам?), а потом один из них пришёл(лет через 5-6), попросился на урок и попросил найти то стихотворение, которое однажды сам сочинил. У него не осталось, а у меня вот сохранилось. Вот зачем, спрашивается? Оказывается, и стихи нужны. Он же Достоевского 9 томов у меня во взрослом состоянии перечитал. Зачем? Он сказал: "Дураком не хочется в глазах приятелей быть".Значит, попал в такую среду. Его ответ тоже может служить ответом на наш вопрос: зачем грамматику учить?

Comment: Людмила, я указал в вопросе ссылку на **ФГОС, в котором ничего нет о придаточных предложениях**:  http://минобрнауки.рф/документы/543 . Пожалуйста, дайте ссылку на ВАШ ФГОС, в котором вы нашли "5.10 Сложные предложения с разными видами связи между частями"

Answer (score 0):

> А вы знаете кого-нибудь взрослого (не специалиста), кто знает русскую грамматику?

Если вы не ставите себе целью найти человека, который бы знал **всю** грамматику (таковых нет даже среди специалистов), то к вашим услугам. 
Или для вас человек, знающий грамматику, - автоматом "специалист"? Тогда вопрос изначально бессмысленный.